# Make First Sheet Display in Excel of Sharepoint in Browser

Tags: 2013, excel, excel-services

I have a Excel Web part and make an excel appear in browser throught this web part. 
There is 4 sheets in excel but when I open the page , firstly the third sheet appears but not he first sheet.
How can I make the first sheet appear?